# Getting wrong ch2 values from sklearn chi2

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, feature-selection

I have a feature vector table which looks like this-

[image]

This a table with 156 columns or features.I want to apply feature selection algorithm to this before applyinh my classification model.

This is what I am using-

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:157].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,0].values

##normalize

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))

X_normalized = scaler.transform(X)


##feature selection

sel = SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')


sel.fit_transform(X_normalized, y)

print(sel.scores_)
```

this is the result of `print(sel.scores_)` I am getting-

[image]

As can be seen they are not all between 0 and 1.

I a referring this research paper as my source-

[image]

[image]

source-http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i256/f06/papers/yang97comparative.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your source that said that value of chi-square should be between `0` and `1`. Imagine as in that equation in the picture say two terms `t` and `c` always co-occur, meaning `D(t|~c)=0` (number of documents with no `c` but `t` in them) and `D(c|~t)=0` (number of documents with `c` in them but no `t`). This means the equation in the snap reduces down to

$\chi^2(t, c) = N*(AD)^2/A^2D^2 = N$.

#### Edit 1:

After reading your comment, I understood you are confused regarding the 'normalised' part. A normalised value does not always mean a scaled value between `0` and `1`. `Normalised value` does mean a value that is scaled appropriately for comparing and in my opinion, the denominator gives that *comparable effect*. The type of normalisation that you are associating this situation to is [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). Check out [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)).

Comment: I added the source in the question

Comment: I am still unable to find the part in the paper where it mentions that the value should be less than `1`. Can you point me to it?

Comment: I have added the picture in the question...in the paper its under the chi square section.....X2 is a normalized value...